# Google Apps + Mailgun Split Delivery

Tags: gmail, google-apps, mailgun

This is a question that was asked a while ago on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/487996/google-apps-mailgun-split-delivery), but was never really answered.

I have attempted to follow multiple guides, however, every single time I test it out I get

`The error that the other server returned was:
550 5.7.1 Relaying denied`

Does anyone have any advice on using Mailgun to achieve split delivery for Google Apps?

Answer (score 2):

The way I do it, is setup a subdomain that has the mx records set to point at mailgun, then on the main domain, any addresses I want to go to mailgun I setup to forward to the subdomain

so say I want website@example.com to go to mailgun, i set this to forward to website@mailgun.example.com

You just need to make sure your code swaps out @mailgun.example.com with @example.com in the to fields if that matters to what you are doing

Hope that helps

Comment: Please add the DNS record that you have added to solve the problem.